# CUDA: nvcc fatal error when trying to make CUDASW++

Tags: cuda

I keep getting:

```
nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm_20' is not defined for option 'gpu-name'
```

My GPU is a GTX 590 and is indeed version 2.0 so that's not the problem. I switched to a lower version (sm_20) and get tons of errors with .h files.

Any ideas on what to try? I'm using cuda 5.0.

Comment: The value `sm_20` is fine, but the nvcc option name has changed. Very old versions of nvcc used the long name `--gpu-name` for the compiler option `-arch`. The long name of `-arch` has changed to `--gpu-architecture` in newer versions (since around CUDA 3.0, I think). See also the NVCC documentation.

Comment: are you certain that you are using cuda 5.0?  I don't think the nvcc in cuda 5 recognizes that option.  I get responses like `nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'gpu-name'`  If you think you are using cuda 5.0 (`nvcc --version`) then inspect carefully the paths that the makefile is using and see if there is an older version of nvcc hanging around somewhere.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: It appears the Makefile for this app was written using an older version of nvcc in which the long name of the option `-arch` was `--gpu-name` (I believe this was the case prior to CUDA 3.0 or thereabouts; it certainly had that long name in very early versions of CUDA). The long name of the `-arch` compiler option has since changed to `--gpu-architecture` and the Makefile for the app will have to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @njuffa, agreed.  But the poster said they have cuda 5 installed.  If I pass `--gpu-name` as an option (which presumably the old makefile is doing) to cuda 5 nvcc, I do not get the error message that the poster indicates.  That error message suggests nvcc comprehends the `--gpu-name` option but not the parameter `sm_20`, which would be consistent behavior with an actual nvcc version of 2.1 or something like that.  the nvcc in cuda 5 *cannot* generate that particular message, I don't think.  I agree the makefile is still messed up also.  I'm trying to point out there may be 2 issues.

Comment: @Robert Crovella Thanks for the clarification. I missed the finer point that there may be not one but two different issues combining here.

Comment: @logan_gabriel: Since you have fairly recent hardware, you may also want to look into more recent versions of CUDASW++: CUDASW++2.0 http://www.biomedcentral.com/1756-0500/3/93/, CUDASW++3.0 http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/14/117

Answer (score 1):

You could try `compute_20` instead of `sm_20`.
Looking at the nvcc documentation in CUDA 5.0, the `--gpu-name` command line option is not mentioned. I guess it is an old option and you should probably instead use the `-arch` and/or `-code` options.